# Improve on these methods for displaying only the country name using Google Maps for EE

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps, low-replace

How would you display only the country name from an entry that has been geocoded with the fieldtype from the excellent [Google Maps for ExpressionEngine](https://www.objectivehtml.com/index.php/google-maps) (GMEE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered two ways of doing this which I thought might be helpful to someone, and am **looking for improvements or better ideas** if people have them.

**Method 1.**

[Use a javascript plugin, as suggested by Justin Kimbrell](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/google-maps/viewthread/6157#20303), author of Google Maps for ExpressionEngine.

**Method 2.**

Use the extremely versatile ['Low Replace' ExpressionEngine plugin](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace) by Lodewijk Schutte:

```
{exp:channel:entries etc}
  {geolocation parse="markers"}
    {markers}
      {exp:low_replace find="(.*,\s)(.*)" replace="$2" regex="yes"}
        {marker:formatted_address}
      {/exp:low_replace}
    {/markers}
  {/geolocation}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Notes:

- Non-essential code has been removed for brevity.
- 'geolocation' is the name of a GMEE fieldtype custom field
- The regex accounts for multiple place names in the format provided by
  Google Maps (e.g. "city, state, country" will be replaced by
  "country").
- Tested on EE v2.5.5 and GMEE v3.1.0